# selected node back color in treeview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I want to change the back color of the selected node in tree view. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

```
treeView1.SelectedNodeStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver;
```

Answer (score -1):

Apply some css on that control.

Following might help:

- [ASP.NET TreeView - CSS Tutorial](http://www.obout.com/t2/tutorial_css.aspx)
- [QuickStart - TreeView](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/navigation/treeview.aspx)